# How can I parse an empty dataframe from webscraping? NoneType error

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

The code that parses all the scraped results in a dataframe is:

```
class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []
    .....
    
    game_data = GameData()
    
    ....


    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        results = None
    
        for url in urls:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```

Sometimes the page does not have any data hence the dataframe is returned as `NoneType` and I get the error:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

How can I parse the empty dataframe with just the defined headers:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code breaks even before Pandas has a chance to parse the data: the `game_data` is `None`, therefore it cannot have attributes (`__dict__`). Because appending no results has no effect, you can just skip an empty data.

```py
        for url in urls:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            ...
```